# why an extra pair of trap and wait

Tags: bash, shell, docker-container

I have the following bash script which runs a process in background and waits for it to finish. If its terminated in between, it is supposed to kill its child process before terminating itself.

This script runs in a docker container.

```
_term() {
  echo "SHELL: Caught SIGTERM signal, propagating to the child"
  kill -TERM "$child" 2>/dev/null
}

trap _term SIGTERM

java -jar RunningProcessWithJMX.jar & # in background

child=$!
wait "$child"  # Line #10
trap - SIGTERM # Line #11
wait "$child"  # Line #12
echo "SHELL: Task finished."
```

I am able to understand this script except the trap and wait on Line #11,#12. Following are my doubts -

1. As per trap's man page, line #11 is resetting the action on SIGTERM. But is there any advantage of this step if one is running it in docker container and the process is of short/long duration?

> If action is '−', the shell shall reset each condition to the default
>          value.

2. As I understand, execution control will not come to Line #11 till process spawned on Line #10 is finished/terminated. can someone help me understand if adding another wait on Line #12 give any advantage? Currently, whenever I run this script outside of docker container, it reports that the child is already terminated.

Comment: Don't think the line 12 is needed, by the time it is hit, the process in `$child` would have terminated, which makes line 11 also unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a good question. Now see below:-

```
trap - SIGTERM # Line #11
```

While you send this signal to a process it does not kill itself immediately. Once a process receive this signal it can operate on certain actions which is vital before it kill itself and it might take some time to complete. In Java there is a method call `attachShutDownHook` which we implement like this.

```
private void attachShutDownHook() {
     Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {                 
         @Override   public void run() {
                System.out.println("Received signal to stop the application");
                System.out.println("Shuting down the application....");
                //here your codes what you want to do at this situation
             }   
         }
     ); 
}
```

So now this method will call in a java application when you execute the `trap` command. Java virtual machine once receive the above `trap` command or command like `kill -8` will call this method in the java application currently running in it.

```
wait "$child"  # Line #12
```

And you definitely want to wait till the child complete its last task list to complete insede `attachShutDownHook` method.

Hope this will help.

Comment: thanks! this was super helpful. I would say this is not specific to java. I tried it with python too. Every process can have its own cleanup routine before it dies. Should we remove the java tag?

Comment: I am not saying this is only for java application. As your script runs a java program I have given the example of java. Yes you can remove the java tag.